# Determining if $R=\left\{(f,g)\mid \exists k\in\Bbb Z,\forall x\in\Bbb Z, \ f(x)g(x)\lt k\right\}$ is an equivalence

Tags: discrete-mathematics, equivalence-relations

I need help with proving whether or not the relation $R=\left\{(f,g)\mid \exists k\in\Bbb Z,\forall x\in\Bbb Z, \ f(x)g(x)\lt k\right\}$ is an equivalence relation on $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$

I understand the basic key components needed in order to determine if the relation is an equivalence relation, like reflexivity, symmetry, and transitivity but i can't seem to find a way to proof reflexivity.

Comment: Something isn't right.  You say this is a relation on $\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}$, but what you define is not a subset of $(\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z})\times(\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z})$.  A binary relation on a set $A$ is a subset of $A\times A$ satisfying the properties you mention.  Can you edit your definition of $R$ to make it more clear?

Comment: I have changed the formatting of the title so as to make it take up less vertical space -- this is a policy to ensure that the scarce space on the main page is distributed evenly over the questions. I would like to ask you to take this into consideration for future questions. Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: Thanks Lord_Farin, I will :)

Comment: @Jared I understand but I'm checking at it again and the problem says: Determine if the relation over the set of functions in $\Bbb Z$ squared is an equivalence relation. The definition of $R$ is the same as well.

Comment: Consider the function $f:\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}$ defined by $f(x)=x$.  There is no $k$ bounding $f(x)\cdot f(x)=x^2$ so the relation is not reflexive.

Comment: @Jared Makes sense to me, so there can't be a $k$ such that $k$ is always greater than $f(x).f(x)$ when $f(x)$ is the identity function. Perhaps you may want to post your comment as an answer?. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the set $A$ of all functions $f:\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}$.  Define an equivalence relation on $A$ by:

$$R=\{(f,g)|\exists k,\forall x,f(x)g(x)<k\}\subset A\times A$$

I claim the relation is symmetric, but not reflexive or transitive.  For symmetry, it suffices to note that $f(x)g(x)=g(x)f(x)$.

As a counterexample to reflexivity, consider $f(x)=x$, and note that $(f,f)\notin R$ because $x^2$ is not bounded.

Finally, consider the functions $f(x)=h(x)=x$ and $g(x)=0$.  Then we have $(f,g),(g,h)\in R$, but $(f,h)\notin R$ so the relation is not transitive.

It follows that the relation is not an equivalence relation.

Comment: Couldn't be any clearer, thanks much Jared.